# Hosting Angularjs 1.x application in tomcat server

Tags: angularjs

How to host angular1 application tomcat server . I have developed one website in angularjs 1.x and want to host that on VPS server purchased from godaddy .

Comment: Please read terms and conditions of StackOverflow before asking such kind of questions.

Comment: is it a static app ? is there any backend application too?

Comment: Yes , this is a static website

Answer (score 0):

If your angularjs build is working properly you should have something like a "dist" folder with your complete app inside.
Enter that directory and create your .war file with:

`$ jar -cvf theNameOfYourApp.war *`

This will create a .war file that you can deploy on your tomcat server.

Comment: Thanks , I am trying to implement this